# Mapping OSM XML to screen coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, xml, josm

I'm creating a simple application that allows visualizing OSM XML data.

I've been following JOSM as a guide, and I'm trying to understand how you can map the long, lat of the XML data to x, y screen coordinates.

I see that there's a link to [slippy map tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) that gives an equation, to map to a tileset once given a zoom factor, long and lat. This may be related to my question but I don't think it gives the proper answer.

I'm good with graphics programming and I understand how to use the bounding box to get the screen coordinates if everything was given in an x,y coordinate information. But, everything is in the lon and lat, which means there has to be a projection.

How does JOSM or another application go from lon, lat to x, y on a flat screen simply using the OSM XML data(like JOSM)?

Answer (score 1):

lon, lat system assumes that earth is round, but our screen is flat so they are not useful for displaying on the screen. The workaround for this is called projection where we convert the lat-lon to x-y cartesian(graph) system. It is a complex process but many tools to help you with that. [proj4](https://proj4.org/) is a good place to start.

This page shows the formula for conversion. https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html